# How can I convert Input.gyro.attitude into a float?

Tags: unity, android, virtual-reality, gyroscope

I am working on a VR project with a 360 video in it. I am trying to set the start rotation of the video to the same rotation as my phones.

How can I convert `Input.gyro.attitude` to a float? That way I can use it in this line of code: `videoSphere.transform.Rotate(initialX - Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x, initialY - Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y, float);`

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: Now that I've had a better chance to review them, this question looks like an [X/Y variant](http://xyproblem.info/) of your original question. It's generally much more productive to ask about the problem you want to solve, than to ask about the method you think might let you cobble together a solution to that problem. If you want to elaborate on a question, use the edit link, don't just re-post the question in a new guise.